# how to overload << operator in c++ to use repeatedly?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Sorry for the not clear title.
Recently I started to learn C++ and I don't know how to overload operator `<<` to make it repeatable.

Here's an example code.

```
class Foo{
private:
int* a;
int idx = 0;

public:
Foo(){a = new int[100];
void operator<< (int a) {arr[idx++] = a;}
```

What `<<` does is basically class get integer number as an operand and save it into `arr`.(Ignore overflow case here)

For example, `a << 100` will add 100 into array.

What I want to do is make `<<` operator can be repeatedly used inline like `a << 100 << 200`
How should I fix above code to allow this function?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Return a reference to `*this`. It's unrelated but you should use a vector to avoid memory leaks. Try to avoid raw `new`

Comment: use `std::vector` and `push_back` or `emplace_back` instead of dynamic array and inserting without checking boundary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The overloaded `Foo::operator<<()` takes actually two arguments:

1. The parameter `int` given as right-hand side
2. The implicit `this` from left-hand side.

To allow chaining of this operator, it should return a reference to the left-hand-side (i.e. `*this`) to become usable at left-hand-side itself.

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
  Foo& operator<<(int a)
  {
    std::cout << ' ' << a;
    return *this;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  foo << 1 << 2 << 3;
}
```

Output:

```
 1 2 3
```

[**Live demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f50372d6130f8baa)

Answer (score 3):

Chaining is enabled by returning a reference to the instance so you can call another method:

```
class Foo{
private:
    std::vector<int> a;   
public:
    Foo(){}
    Foo& operator<< (int a) {
        arr.push_back(a);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Now you can call `f << 100 << 200 << 42;`.

Note that I replaced the array with a `std::vector` to make `Foo` less broken (unless you have a descrutor that you did not show it was leaking memory, you could fix that, but then still copying would cause problems, in short you need to respect the rule of 3/5 when you own a resource, using a `std::vector` makes things much simpler).

PS: Same works for other methods. You simply call another method on the returned reference to `this`. Note that operators are just methods (with some syntactic sugar) and to see that you can write as well `f.operator<<(100).operator<<(200).operator<<(42);`.

Answer (score 2):

Return a reference to `*this`. It's unrelated but you should use a vector to avoid memory leaks. Try to avoid raw `new`

```
class Foo{
private:
    std::vector<int> a;

public:
    Foo &operator<< (int a) {
        arr.push_back(a);
        return *this;
    }
};
```